# Why do my arms go to sleep at night after strenuous workout?

Tags: training, sleep

I have this problem always especially after forearm training. Depending on how intense the training was my arms go to sleep 1-5 times per night. After a few days without training it doesn't happen anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different reasons for your limbs (in your case arms) go to sleep, as you can read here:

http://www.drlamb.com/paresthesia.htm

In your case I guess it's because of pressure. Is it possible that you sleep on your arms? That happened to me a lot since then I try not to put my head on my arms.

An other possibility is a vitamin deficiency. While you train YOU HAVE TO EAT HEALTHY! I just don't get people who work out 4 times a week and don't give a sh.. about what they eat. Eating is half your work out people!

Hope you'll find out what it is exactly.